# Set Extended Attributes with AppleScript Objc

Tags: macos, applescript, applescript-objc

So I am looking for a way to set Mac specific extended attributes (specifically kMDItemWhereFroms) for a file (Image File, Jpg) using AppleScript or AppleScript-Objc.

There is a command line tool that will do this `xattr -w kMDItemWhereFroms` . The problem is that on the several machines that I have access to (10.12, 10.13, and 10.14) when you run this command as a do shell script from within an AppleScript it does not work, the metadata is not added to the file. If I set Script Debugger to debug mode, and go through the script step by step it will actually set the metadata, but since that is not the way I am running the script, it is more of an interesting fluke than anything else. I have tried running the command with both "com.apple.metadata:" included and not included with the shell script and that makes no difference.

I have tried running my script through SD, Script Editor and osascript, and they all fail to update the metadata. So I am thinking that this tool might be broken when called from an AppleScript.

I found `setxattr` but that looks like it only applies to C.

So my questions are
1. Is there a way to set the extended attributes of a file on MacOS using Aobjc? if not then
2. Is there a way to get setxattr to work with either version of AppleScript? Probably not so
3. Any ideas how I might be able to get the command line tool `xattr -w kMDItemWhereFroms` to work when using scripting?

This is more of an annoyance for me, I am just being stubborn with wanting the source of the file to show up in the "Where From" data in the Get Info window from the Finder. I already am setting some metadata for the file using exiftool. So it is more of an interesting problem for me, than a critical problem that I must try and solve now. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an Automator example a little while ago in [this answer on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386608/321333).

Comment: @red_menace You are still using "xattr" to write the metadata to the file. And that is not working for me when I run it from a script.

Comment: `xattr` is a shell utility like any other, and is one of the standard ways to set `whereFroms` and `userTags` metadata.  Those handlers date from about 10.9 Mavericks or so - I haven't had a problem using them from a standard account on any of my machines up through 10.15 Catalina.  Are you having permissions or accessibility issues?

Comment: @red_menace So I guess I figured out what was going on. xattr really wants to be run LAST. I am also running EXIFTOOL in the same script, and when I try to do xattr before ediftool it doesn't work (no metadata is written), but when I do it AFTER efixtool writes it's metadata, then run xattr the metadata "sticks". I guess I can close this question, as I have figured it out.